I don't know who to talk to vs. I don't know whom to talk to (which one is more used in colloquial English?)

I don't know who to talk to. vs. I don't know whom to talk to.

Which one is more used in colloquial English?

Which one is more colloquial to you? You do know that these types of questions will be closed, right? No opinion from you or research.

@Lambie Meh, distinguishing between modes of formality is pretty hard to research. Even if you did an ngram, it's hard to parse between formal and informal usage. I give this one a pass.

@AndyBonner First, one has to look at the standard explanation: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/who-vs-whom-its-not-as-complicated-as-you-might-think/. Then, one can move on to how people actually speak.


Just so we're clear, "whom" is supported by how our grammar works. A very simple sentence would be "I talk to him," not "to he." If we turn this into a question, it would be "I talk to whom?," or in the more common inverted form, "Whom do I talk to?"
It's also worth mentioning that there was a "rule" for a long time that you shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition. Pretty much everyone agrees now that it was a silly rule and shouldn't be enforced. But its legacy is still felt enough that, in an academic setting, "Whom do I talk to" feels uncomfortable. (The version that that rule would approve would be "To whom do I talk?".)
With that out of the way, to answer your real question: In all but the most formal settings, it's very rare to use "whom" for the direct object. So rare, in fact, that even in a very formal setting, the "correct" version feels awkward and uncomfortable. And, like the old "end with a preposition" rule, anyone who insists on "whom" might be regarded as being in the wrong and unreasonably ignoring the significance of common usage. If I were writing a sentence like this in an academic context, I might reword to avoid it altogether, something like "[The ethnologists] were unsure where to turn for answers."



I don't know who to talk to. vs. I don't know whom to talk to.

Who to talk to is common in conversation.   It is also more popular in written text than to whom to talk.
Ngram
I won’t recommend the use of whom to talk to.
